# Image not showing using it in css

Tags: html, css

I am newbie so don't mind my question.
I am trying to insert an image using css bt it doesn't show in the page.
Here is my code :

```
<div id="outerWrapper">
   <div id="header">
       <div id="wave">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my css is :

```
#outerWrapper #header #wave{background:url("generic/wave.png") bottom left no-repeat;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:960px;height:193px;z-index:100;}
```

The image path is correct. So help me please :)

Comment: And that's whole css? Isolated - your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/afd1vnw8/ (you should add position:relative to container, of course)

Comment: why     #outerWrapper #header #wave ?
#wave only would've been sufficiant, and better for performance.

Comment: Why have all of our answers been down voted? These are all perfectly reasonable answers.

Comment: your css path is obviously not correct and/or your your image path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code works for me.
Sometimes a file extension will be uppercase, you may want to double check that.
Here is my source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #outerWrapper #header #wave{
            background:url("PathToImage.png") bottom left no-repeat;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:960px;
            height:193px;
            z-index:100;
            border:1px solid black;//This is to make sure the size of div and position of background image are correct.
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerWrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="wave">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK it works for me, but y it is not working in the separate css file ??

Comment: Your path to the image needs to be relative to the CSS file not the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Bilal Zafar, created files with your code, it worked for me here, here the link with the test [neows.com.br/imagem-bg.rar](http://neows.com.br/imagem-bg.rar) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently modified your `css` file, try clearing your cache as sometimes the old `css` file is saved.